# In digital image restoration field, what is shift-invarient blurs?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I am working in digital image restoration field. According to it the image degradation model is defined like that:

**g(x,y) = h(x,y)*f(x,y) + n(x,y)**

many times i have studied that the **blur-kernel** is **shift-invariant**, can anyone please explain that what does it mean.? i have already searched it on **Google**, but i did not get satisfactory answer that i can tell during my presentation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-invariant_system

Comment: i have mentioned that i have already Google it.

Comment: Sure, but what part of the Wikipedia article are you having trouble with?  (i.e. " if y(n) is the response of the system to x(n), then y(n-k) is the response of the system to x(n-k)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift invariant means that if some arbitrary value *x* is added to (or subtracted from) every element of a sample (in this case the pixels covered by the kernel), then the result of the kernel is also affected by the addition (or subtraction) of the value *x*.

It's most easily understood if you consider a blur kernel as a simple average (mean) rather than a Gaussian or whatever.

So if you have pixels with values `v1, v2, v3 ... vn`

with an average, `A = (v1 + v2 + v3 + ... vn) / n`,

then if you add some value `x` to each pixel (i.e. `v1 + x, v2 + x, v3 + x ... vn + x`),

the new average will simply be `A + x`.

So the output of the convolution is shifted by the same amount as each of the inputs. Hence **shift invariant**.